# SLAPI: ssh_keys argument while creating VSI doesn't work?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a VSI using SLAPI [ python ] as follows:

```
object= client['Virtual_Guest'].createObject({
    'hostname': 'ssh-key-test',
    'domain': 'test.org',
    'startCpus': 1,
    'maxMemory': 1024,
    'datacenter': {'name': 'mydc'},
    'hourlyBillingFlag': 'true',
    'ssh_keys': [ssh_id],
    'operatingSystemReferenceCode': 'UBUNTU_LATEST',
    'localDiskFlag': 'false'
})
```

The call passes successfully, I can login to the VM using it's root password. But I see .ssh/authorized_keys file is remaining empty. I have made sure the ssh_id I am passing above is the correct id [obtained from SshKeyManager-->list_keys(). Also, if I copy the key manually, it works as expected. 
I was expecting the above API will inject the key into authorized_keys, is that not right ?

I looked at softlayer documentation and wherever I could find relevant information, but did not find an answer to my question.

If the API is not working as expected, any clues on what might be happening here ?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.